# iPhone UIColor getrgb strange alpha value

Tags: ios, objective-c, alpha, uicolor

I am trying to get `RGB`, alpha value from `UIColor` variable.

```
  currentColor = [[UIColor alloc]init];
  currentColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
  [currentColor getRed: &red green: &green blue: &blue alpha: &alpha];
```

I get `-1.998975` for `alpha` value sometimes.
As I know, `alpha` should be between 0 and 1. 
I really wonder where it comes.
Any advice?

Comment: Can you provide an example for `currentColor` when you get a strange `alpha`? Keep in mind that calling the `UIColor getRed:green:blue:alpha:` method won't work with white, black, and grays (depending on how those colors were referenced).

Comment: rgb values are gotten normally, only alpha value has a problem.

Comment: OK, but you still need to provide some examples. Post some code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: What is the return value of the getRed:green:blue:alpha: method call? Does it return YES or NO? If the value is NO, it couldn't be converted.

Comment: Like I said, you can't use this method with `UIColor blackColor`. That color is using a different color model other than RGB. Read the docs for the `UIColor getRed:green:blue:alpha:` method. It clearly states that it only works for colors in the RGB color model.

Comment: Side note - why do you first create an empty color object and then throw out the value? There is no need for that.

Answer (score 0):

So i tried your code,

```
  UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];

  CGFloat red;
  CGFloat green;
  CGFloat blue;
  CGFloat alpha;

  BOOL converted = [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

  NSLog(@"Converted: %@", converted?@"YES":@"NO");

  NSLog(@"Red: %f", red);
  NSLog(@"Green: %f", green);
  NSLog(@"Blue: %f", blue);
  NSLog(@"Alpha: %f", alpha);
```

And you are right, there is something wrong with the alpha value. But it seems to work for redColor, blueColor etc... One thin I noticed is that the BOOL converted has the value NO when trying to get the black color rgba components. I can't tell you why this happens. I guess you will just have to work around it.

I also noticed that if you create a black color with

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
```

You can get all 4 components (rgb and a) with the correct values. I wonder how the blackColor creates the color, if it does it in another color space or something making the conversion to RGBA impossible.

Comment: `UIColor blackColor` is made using a gray scale color modal (along with `whiteColor` and the various gray colors. This is why `getRed:green:blue:alpha` returns NO. The color isn't in the RGB color model. And this is why it works when you create a black color the long way.

Answer (score 0):

Tired the same code but i got 0

```
UIColor * currentColor = [[UIColor alloc]init];
currentColor = [UIColor blackColor];
CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
[currentColor getRed: &red green: &green blue: &blue alpha: &alpha];

NSLog(@"%f",alpha);
```

Output

```
2013-04-30 10:16:44.509 TrialsError[38563:11303] 0.000000
```